# Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1 MultiView in Popover mode is broken

Tags: delphi, regression, firemonkey, access-violation

I updated Delphi to Tokyo 10.2.1 then recompiled and installed my iOS app only to find that the MultiView component in popover mode is now broken.  I also ran the MultiViewDemo project in the Samples folder (Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\MultiView) and found the same problem.  An access violation occurs on the second attempt of selecting the MasterButton.  If anyone has experienced the same error and has found a workaround of some kind I would appreciate knowing your solution.

Comment: Submit a bug report

Answer (score 3):

copy FMX.Controls.pas to your project directory and modify as follows:

```
function TControl.GetHeight : Single;

begin
     Result := 0;
     if FSize <> nil
        then begin
        if FSize.PlatformDefault
           then Result := FSize.DefaultValue.Height
           else Result := FSize.Height;
        end;
end;

function TControl.GetWidth : Single;

begin
     Result := 0;
     if FSize <> nil
        then begin
        if FSize.PlatformDefault
           then Result := FSize.DefaultValue.Width
           else Result := FSize.Width;
        end;
end;
```